# Define default locale and treat exceptions for Spring Locale Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, locale

Is it possible to define a default locale that should be loaded in case the user sets **?lang=unknownlang**  ?

In my spring-servlet.xml i have:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="pt" />
</bean>
```

Also if i specify invalid characters in my url param like ?lang=p@t, spring throws an exception that should be handled, how would i go about that ?

```
Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed&#59; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Locale part &quot;&#39;&quot; contains invalid characters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve these problems.

Regarding the default locale, spring will solve that internally as long as there is a default .properties file in the resource bundle.

So in my case there would have to be a xxx_pt.properties xxx_en.properties and a xxx.properties.

For the exception handling I actually had to override the preHandle method of the LocaleChangeInterceptor class and catch the exception:

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="com.xxx.xxx.LanguageExceptionHandler">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
```

**LanguageExceptionHandler.java**

```
public class LanguageExceptionHandler extends LocaleChangeInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        try {
            super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            DebugLogger.writeError("ServletException", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            DebugLogger.writeError("IllegalArgumentException", e);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Although according to [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9456), invalid characters should be handled differently in newer versions of Spring.

Comment: i have file like messages.properties ,messages_en-IN.properties and messages_en-HI.properties ...where should i write and run LanguageExceptionHandler code? I am using spring with xml(not java config) I have error as "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Locale part "en-IN""