# restrict invalid characters using LocaleChangeInterceptor

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization

how to handle locale that is loaded with value lang=unknownlang ?

In my web-servlet i have:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define default locale and treat exceptions for Spring Locale Interceptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786962/define-default-locale-and-treat-exceptions-for-spring-locale-interceptor)